# failed to build project in eclipse with android after add blackberry

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry

I install a blackberry developer plugin in my eclipse indigo that already installed by android. But after i installed the blackberry, my eclipse get an error. The error message is **The building workspace has encountered a problem**

> Errors occurred during the build.
>
> Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'AMDP3'.
>
> net/rim/ejde/external/sourceMapper/SourceMapperAccess

I think it's because my eclipse is confused because it tried to build an android project in the "blackberry way".

My questions are:

1. Can 1 eclipse contain android and blackberry plugins (i have searched and some say yes while some say no...so i tried to do it)
2. According to my 1st question, what should i do now?

Thanks
**Answer : According to the chosen answer, i recommend you to install 2 different eclipse, but if it's to late just uninstall your BB plugin : CLICK HELP->ABOUT->INSTALLED SOFTWARE->UNINSTALL**

Comment: This is the link where you can get the newest eclipse with BB environment :
https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While theoretically you can, I'd recommend against it.

I've had a couple of bad experiences where installing BB plugin in eclipse uninstalled some metrics plugin I have already installed. Since then, I tend to use separate eclipses for each platform. Never had this problem with Android plugin. I also refrain to upgrade old BB plugins installs to the newer version, because of compatibility issues.

I usually download the eclipse+BB plugin package available in BlackBerry Developers page, because it comes with the setup almost done, so I can save some time.

If you are going to do it, try to install the problematic one (BB) first, then the Android one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :D
But its to late for me, what should i do now?is it okay to just remove the BB plugin?or is there any other way?i hope my eclipse could work at least with the android
Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

If your question is: `Can I run a single instance of Eclipse for both Android and BlackBerry development?`

The answer is: Yes.

Not sure about your error though. In case it helps here's my list of installed software for my working version of Eclipse. [image: Eclipse - installed software]

Comment: Thanks for your help..maybe you did something after adding newsoftware? :D